# columns/alignment with itemize

Tags: tables, beamer, lists, align

I'm trying to make alignment points in a list environment. The following code gives me an error, but it almost compiles to what I want, just missing the bullet points. I must be misunderstanding something about align and/or tabular and how they work with linebreaks. Guidance appreciated!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{itemize}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \item Topic Apple: &Something to say about it \\
        \item Topic Watermelons: &Something different
    \end{tabular}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I should mention that this isn't beamer-specific...I was hasty there because this arose while I was working on a presentation. If I just use the article class then I still have the same issue. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, it is sort-of beamer-specific, since beamer's handling of lists is so much different from the usual one that generic LaTeX solutions will possibly not work here.

Comment: That's true--what I meant was just that the place to start might be with a standard class and then see if the solution also works in beamer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this particular mixture of itemize and tabular out of the box.  But the  [listliketab](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listliketab/) package can help.  The purpose of that package is to make tables looks like lists.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{listliketab} 
    \storestyleof{itemize} 
        \begin{tabular}{Lll}
            \textbullet & Topic Apple: &Something to say about it \\
            \textbullet & Topic Watermelons: &Something different
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{listliketab}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Works in beamer and other all other classes (that I know of).

Comment: thanks, that works great. Do you know how I can inherit the bullet style from my beamer template when I use \storestyleof ?

Comment: Oh...lets see, so I think the way to go about this is to replace itemize with \usebeamertemplate*{itemize item}. But if I do that I get an error "You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode."--looking at the beamer templates they do have \raise commands in them.

Comment: Gee I'm a smart one...replace \textbullet by \usebeamertemplate*{itemize item} and it works. Because, you know, that makes sense, unlike what I just wrote.

Comment: That's right.  `\usebeamertemplate*` is better here than `\usebeamertemplate` without the star.  I had to look it up to find out why, but basically it will surround the item label with a group.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet}ll}
        Topic Apple: &Something to say about it \\
        Topic Watermelons: &Something different
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image]

You can also change the `\textbullet` by, for example adding another column which will hold the item marker (which you can then control using `beamer`).

Comment: That seems like a good solution; do you happen to know what I need to put in to get beamer to replicate my itemize/enumerate style and the correct spacing after the bullet?

Comment: Nice. But there should be some space after the `\textbullet`.

Comment: I tried to add \usebeamertemplate{itemize item} into the tabular definition, but got errors....my tex-foo isn't good enough to do this properly...anyone else want to take it from here?

Comment: Oh, adding the space is easy, just add \hspace*{\labelsep} after the bullet.

Comment: Thanks for that - but this doesn't seem to preserve neither line width, nor indentation, in two-column documents...

Answer (score 4):

Since other suggestions here didn't work for my two-column document style, here is my plain-TeX hack to achieve something similar:

```
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}%
\item{\ \hbox to 3cm{Topic Apple: \hfill}\texttt{Something} to say about it}
\item{\ \hbox to 3cm{Topic Watermelons: \hfill}\texttt{Something} different}
\end{itemize}
```

Here is a brief explanation (before I forget it :) ):

- the `\itemsep` and `\parskip` solve a different problem in my document (*I include them since I'm not sure if they have an effect on the rest or not*)
- The first space '`\`' in the `\item`, is to cheat the `\itemize` environment - so it thinks it starts with plain text (*otherwise, Latex will typeset everything in the first `\hbox` **above** the bullet point*)
- The '`\hbox to 3cm{}`' creates a box 3cm wide, in which the contents will be typeset - however, by default, the text contents (i.e., the 'glues')  in this `\hbox` will be stretched across the entire width of the `\hbox`
- To solve this stretching problem, we enter a '`\hfill`' at the end of the `\hbox`: thus, the text in the `\hbox` is typeset first, and then the `\hfill` inserts a space stretching to the end of the 3cm width - which effectively shows the text as 'raggedright' (i.e., left aligned)
- (*I had a '`\texttt{}`' word where I wanted the alignment indent to happen in my own case, so I included it here too*)

Of course, to have this code usable, one should use a length variable before it:

```
\newlength{\tmplen}
\setlength{\tmplen}{3cm}
```

and then use `\tmplen` in the `\item`s instead, as in:

```
...
\item{\ \hbox to \tmplen{Topic Apple: \hfill}\texttt{Something} to say about it}
...
```

... since you'll have to manually set the box width with this approach.

Well, hope this helps someone,

Cheers!