# How to create column - aligned entrys in a itemize enviromenment (in 2nd. level)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, itemize

i'd like to `itemize` a list of properties for my experiment protocol. What I want is:

[image: What I want]

there is some nice way to align itemized entrys in [How to create columns within an itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72701/how-to-create-columns-within-an-itemize-environment)
and in [columns/alignment with itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/columns-alignment-with-itemize) but I can't get it properly done in the 2nd level itemize. Here is what I got at the moment

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}



\begin{itemize}
    \item Analysewaage
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}

\begin{itemize}

 \item Topic Apple:
 \item Topic Watermelon:


\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}
  \item[] Something to say about it
  \item[] Something to say about it
\end{itemize} \\

\end{tabular}

\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @karlkoeller et. al.: I missed that one. Thanks, it sure does help. Is there something I am supposed to do or just leave the question as it is? Sorry, first time duplicated a question.